# SQL Dynamic Query based on user input in PowerBI

Tags: sql-server, query, dynamic-sql, powerbi

I am pulling data from inSQL using the SQL Query below:

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF

SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(INSQL, "SELECT DateTime, [X],[Y], [Z], [A]

FROM WideHistory

WHERE wwRetrievalMode = 'Cyclic'

AND wwResolution = 1000

AND wwVersion = 'Latest'

AND DateTime >= '20210601 20:02:33.000'

AND DateTime <= '20210607 20:02:34.000'")
```

I'm using this table in PowerBI and want [X],[Y], [Z], [A] & the DateTime values to dynamically change based on user input.

Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated. I am new to PowerBI and SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Write the query to provide the data set you want. Then add filters and slicers in PowerBi.

PowerBI needs access to the full dataset before it can filter it down.
All of the filtering options you need can be done within PowerBi.

If you can guarantee that the Resolution and Version filters will always apply you can leave these in the query. But if you want date ranges greater than you sample query you'll need to remove the date filters.

Depending upon the features you want you may want to include a date dimension in the data model.